# Prove that this sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

While trying to prove some Hardy-type inequalities, I should claim that the following sequence is decreasing
$$
G(n) = f(n) \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} f(k)\right]^{p-1}, 
$$

where the sequence $f(n)$ is decreasing and  $0<p<=1$.

I tried to prove that
$$
G(n+1) -G(n)<0
$$
as follows
$$
G(n+1)-G(n) =f(n+1)\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)
^{p-1}-f(n)\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1} \\
\leq f(n)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)
^{p-1}-f(n)\left( n\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1},
$$
but could not estimate the right-hand side, Any help with this issue?

Comment: Why it is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ and not $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}$?

Comment: The original one from $k=1$ to $n-1$.

Comment: It might be better to examine G(n+1)/G(n).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I already tried it before

Comment: When $f(n)>0$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle G(n)=f(n)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\right)^{p-1}$ with $0\le p\le 1$ and $f(n)$ decreasing then $G(n)$ is increasing.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn The inner summation is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$. How did you prove that it is increasing one?

Comment: @Ramy if it was what I assumed plus $f$ is increasing - I missed it, then $\displaystyle G(n+1)-G(n)=f(n+1)\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(k)\right)-f(n)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)\ge f(n)\left((n+1)^{1-p}(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}f(k))^{p-1}-(n)^{1-p}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k))^{p-1}\right)$ then the right most one to be greater than $0$ is equivalent to $$\left(1+\dfrac{f(n)}{\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)}\right)^{1-p}\le\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{1-p}\Longleftrightarrow nf(n+1)\le \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$$ this is really confusing as it is true when $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn Actually, I followed the same spirit of your proof with some modifications yesterday and got a solution to the original problem which asserts that the sequence $G(n)$ is decreasing as long as the sequence $f(n)$.

Comment: @Ramy So, could you please give us your whole proof with entire conditions of your original problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<p\leq 1$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(n+1)-F(n) &=&f(n+1)\left( \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)
^{p-1}-f(n)\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1} \\
&=&f(n+1)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)
^{p-1}-f(n)\left( n\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1},
\end{eqnarray*}
but since $f(n)$ is non-increasing (that is $f(n+1)\leq f(n)$) and $\left(
n\right) ^{1-p}\leq \left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}$, it follows that
\begin{equation}
F(n+1)-F(n)\leq f(n)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)
^{p-1}-f(n)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1},
\label{q}
\end{equation}
Now, since $f(n)\geq 0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) &\equiv &f(1)+f(2)+\cdots +f(n-1)+f(n) \\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)+f(n),
\end{eqnarray*}
then (note $p-1<0$)
\begin{equation*}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right) ^{p-1}=\left(
f(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1}\leq \left(
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1},
\end{equation*}
We finally get that
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(n+1)-F(n) &\leq &f(n)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left(
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1}-f(n)\left( n+1\right) ^{1-p}\left(
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\right) ^{p-1} \\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}

which asserts that $F(n)$ is also non-increasing as long as $f(n)$.